# Mockito How to test anonymous inner class method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, powermockito

In below class i have anonymous inner class so how can test it with mockito. Please check below code

```
// Service class
@Component("someServiceClass")
public class SomeServiceClassImpl implements SomeServiceClass {

 @Autowired
 RepoClass repo;

 LoadingCache < String, ClientDetails > clientDetailsCache = 
CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
  .build(new CacheLoader < String, ClientDetails > () {
   @Override
   public ClientDetails load(String clientId) throws Exception {

    OauthClientMapping client = repo.findByClientId(clientId);

    return someObject;
   }
  });

 @Override
 public void method(String id) {
  String param = request.getParameter("param");
 }
}
```

Comment: Please be more accurate. How this inner class is used? Do You attempt to write test yourself, If yes post it here.

Comment: Hi .. i need to cover each line written in SomeServiceClassImpl class by mockito junit test case